# Using the AWS SDK - Error PKIX path building failed running inside an AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I'm getting this random error: `error: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` using the sdk of ssm to get parameter store values. 
I'm running the code inside was lambda function with Java8.

The version used is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssm/1.11.788

Comment: What is the url of the http request you are trying to reach? It looks like you are trying to connect to an https endpoint where the cert being served is not from a known provider

Comment: @PatrickMagee is right, this is what you'd normally see if you're trying to establish an HTTPS connection with a host which uses a certificate from a CA which itself is not Javas cacerts.
But I'd be quite surprized if Amazon would run J-Lambdas on Java installation which would not include Amazon CA certs in `cacerts` by default.

Comment: I have the exact same problem did you find a solution @German? I'm trying to access aws s3 and encounter the same kind of exception

Comment: I fixed that changing the SDK version.